# How to convert an object of key values to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I  want to convert an object of key values to an array of objects in javascript

```
var obj={"name1":"value1","name2":"value2",...};
```

How can i convert it to

```
arr=[{"name":"name1","value":"value1"},{"name":"name2","value":"value2"},...];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `array#map` and `Array#push`

```js
var obj={"name1":"value1","name2":"value2"};
var res=[];
Object.keys(obj).map(a => res.push({name:a , value:obj[a]}))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (ES6):

```
const arr = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => {
  return {
    name,
    value
  }
});
```

Another answer (ES5):

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return {
    name: key,
    value: obj[key]
  }
});
```

Comment: Don't use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) as it is *not* ES6 but still only a draft.

Comment: [*Object.entries*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object.entries) is ECMAScript 2018 (as str says, still a draft). By "ES6" I guess you mean ECMAScript 2015 aka [*ECMA–262 ed 6*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I won't edit the post to keep your comments valid.